# XAMPP Apache server has wrong path

Tags: apache, path, xampp

When I fire up XAMPP and try to start mySQL and Apache, I get a similar error for both:

```
12:07:22 PM  [Apache]   Apache Service detected with wrong path
12:07:22 PM  [Apache]   Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
12:07:22 PM  [Apache]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
12:07:22 PM  [Apache]   Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
12:07:22 PM  [Apache]   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
```

I have searched high and low for the program that might be changing the path, but I already uninstalled all my Apache stuff I had when I was using a full, bona fide LAMP stack. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling XAMPP, but that did not accomplish anything.

The error readout says to change the settings in the XAMPP Control Panel, but I cannot find where to change the path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***I was able to fix this!!!***

Had the same problems as stated above, made sure nothing was using port 80 and still not working and getting the message that Apache and Mysql were detected with wrong path.

I did install XAMPP once before, uninstalled and reinstalled. I even manually uninstalled but still had issues.

The fix. Make sure you backup your system first!!!

```
Start Services via Control Panel>Admin Tools (also with Ctrl+R and services.msc)

Look for Apache and mySQL services. Look at the patch indicated in the description (right click on service then click on properties). Chances are that you have Apache listed twice, one from your correct install and one from a previous install. Even if you only see one, look at the path, chances are its from a previous install and causing your install not to work. In either case, you need to delete those incorrect services.

a. Got to command prompt (run as administrator): Start > all programs > Accessories > right click on Command Prompt > Select 'run as administrator'

b. on command prompt type sc delete service, where service is the service you're wanting to delete, such as apache2.1 (or sc delete Apache2.4). It should be exactly as it appears in your services. If the service has spaces such as apache 2.1 then enter it in quotes, i.e. sc delete "apache 2.1"

c. press enter. Now refresh or close/open your services window and you'll see its gone.
```

DO THIS for all services that XAMPP finds as running with incorrect path.

Once you do this, go head and restart the XAMPP control panel (as administrator) and viola!!! all works. No conflicts

Answer (score 1):

I found A solution. This may not work in every case.

1. I went into Config (on the XAMPP Control Panel) and configured Apache and MySQL to both run automatically when starting XAMPP Control Panel, and restarted Control Panel.
2. Under "Service" on the left side of the window, I clicked the check mark next to Apache. I was prompted to confirm that I wanted to uninstall that service. I said Yes and it uninstalled
3. I then clicked the red x next to Apache and said Yes to the prompt. It reinstalled and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as stated above.
you might have noticed a green tick to the left of Apache.
First ,  you need to uninstall the service by clicking on it. 
then repress the same icon and install the services.
It should work fine.